# Word for word meaning of "to beard a lion in his den"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I'm going to illustrate a word for word meaning of some English idioms. Just a fun drawing. Get stuck with the phrase “to beard a lion in his own den”.
I understand the meaning “to confront someone on his own territory”. But I need to draw it in exact words.

Would it be evident to English speakers if I draw a character who shaves the lion or cuts his beard with scissors? Maybe not a good idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a drawing, not usage of English.

Comment: Anna, it's strange. Where did you hear that?

Comment: @Tristanr - I had never heard it either. See [here](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/07/beard-to/) for some history. It's very old.

Comment: The interesting question is whether the verb phrase _to beard a lion_ means to **deprive** the lion of a beard (like _to milk the cow_ or _to seed the pepper_), or to **provide** a beard for the lion (like _to water the cow_ or _to seed the lawn_). Neither would be very safe, of course, in the lion's den, but one wonders about [the Verbing involved](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf).

Comment: ... and of course, a lion could be 'a very brave person' [AHD 3a]

Comment: @medica, thanks for the link. It's very strange. It made me think of this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FavRPQkmTVg

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest attaching a fake beard to the lion with a string tied behind his neck, because ["to beard"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beard?s=t) can mean "to supply with a beard", but it won't mean to shave, trim, or remove a beard.

I think if the lion and the other character seem to be surrounded by stone or earth you might give the impression of "in his den."

Edit: I initially thought that you were trying for a humorous image that expressed the words of the image as a counterpoint to the meaning of the idiom. But if it's a more direct depiction that's needed, then the character looking fierce and grabbing the lion's mane beneath his chin would work well and show what the words of the idiom are literally trying to express.

Comment: It's actually sense 6 which is meant here, which could provide a much more immediate image.

Comment: Good thought, @AndrewLeach. I edited my answer to take in that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

To "beard" Merriam-Webster's says, means either "to confront and oppose with boldness, resolution and often effrontery: DEFY" or "to furnish with a beard." The clear meaning of "beard a lion in his den" is the former—that is, to meet the lion beard-to-beard in his own stronghold and defy him there. So why not depict a bearded person confronting a bearded lion face-to-face and beard-to-beard? Alternatively, you could show someone awkwardly gluing or taping or drawing a beard on a lion.

---

By the way, the first two instances of "beard the lion" that a Google Books search finds are from the mid-1700s. From Paul Whitehead, "[Manners: A Satire](http://books.google.com/books?id=JaJYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22beard+the+lion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UutrU66wHsPHoASzloD4Cg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22beard%20the%20lion%22&f=false)" (1739):

> Pope writes unhurt — but know, 'tis dif'rent quite
>
> To beard the Lion, and to crush the Mite.
>
> Safe may he dash the Statesman in each Line,
>
> Those dread his Satire, who dare punish mine.

From Tobias Smollett, [*The Regicide: Or, James the First, of Scotland*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ix8OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22beard+the+lion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4OhrU-mfNY7yoASB_IGABQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22beard%20the%20lion%22&f=false) (1749):

> **Dunbar.** When the Battle joins,
>
> Thou shalt be answered.—
>
> **Stuart.** When, the Battle joins !—
>
> —Away, Dissembler !— Sooner would'st thou beard
>
> The Lion in his Rage, than fairly meet
>
> My Valour on the Plain !

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see a mellow-looking lion getting its mane put into corn-rows or rasta dreads at the hands of an equally mellow-looking dude. I mean, the only way both parties would consent to such an arrangement would be to be ... mellow. If you catch my drift.

Comment: IconDaemon, there's something like that here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iox86q2JuHA